# Vue: On render, window scrolls to the top

Tags: javascript, dom, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to understand why when I make a table row visible or invisible, the page is re-rendered from the top.  The window automatically scrolls back to the top.  As such, I have to scroll back down to the component.

I'm using Vue 2.6.12.  Testing on Google Chrome, but the same issue occurs in Firefox, too.

The template below presents the element that I'm working with.

The function toggleScorecardVisibility() will toggle the visible state of the scorecard.

The table row will become visible, per the snippet below:

```
<tr v-show="scorecard.visible" class='border mb-2'>
```

Whenever the scorecard visible state changes, the window returns to the top of the page.

I've tried a number of things, including disabling window.onscroll, but nothing I've tried seems to prevent this behavior.  I've also tried positioning the element (the vue $ref) using the scrollTo function.

Is there a way to prevent the window from scrolling back to the top of the page and remain focused on the TR element that has just been exposed?

Any pointers are helpful.

```
        <template v-for="scorecard in paginatedList">
            <tr v-bind:key="scorecard.id"  :ref="'ref-scorecard-'+scorecard.id">
                <td class="position-relative">
                    <player :assignedPlayer="scorecard" :options="{'showIndex': 2, 'showRole': false, 'nameFormat': 3, 'sub_on_new_line': 1, 'detail': 1}" />
                </td>
                <td class='text-center align-middle'>{{scorecard.player.flight}}</td>
                <td class='text-center align-middle'>{{scorecard.gtotal}}</td>
                <td class='text-center align-middle'>{{scorecard.ntotal}}</td>
                <td class='text-center align-middle'>{{scorecard.ptotal}}</td>
                <td class='text-center align-middle'>{{scorecard.points_adjustment}}</td>
                <td class='text-center align-middle'>{{getSkins(scorecard)}}</td>
                <td class='text-center'>
                    <div>
                        <a @click="toggleScorecardVisibility(scorecard.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-transparent-dark text-gray-500 m-0" href="#" role="button" :id="'scorecard_' + scorecard.id"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Scorecard Details" >
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-clipboard">
                                <path d="M16 4h2a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H6a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h2"></path><rect x="8" y="2" width="8" height="4" rx="1" ry="1"></rect>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                        <a @click="onShowRebuildScorecardConfirmationModel(scorecard.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon text-red m-0" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Reset Scorecard" >
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-refresh-cw"><polyline points="23 4 23 10 17 10"></polyline>
                                <polyline points="1 20 1 14 7 14"></polyline><path d="M3.51 9a9 9 0 0 1 14.85-3.36L23 10M1 14l4.64 4.36A9 9 0 0 0 20.49 15"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <transition name='fade' :key='-scorecard.id'>
                <tr v-show="scorecard.visible" class='border mb-2'>
                    <td colspan='8'>
                        <scorecard 
                            :scorecardId="scorecard.id" 
                            :numberOfHoles="store.event_plan.play_length == 0 ? 9 : 18"
                            :scorecard="scorecard"
                            :course="store.course.tees[scorecard.tee.id]"
                            @scorecard-updated="scorecardUpdated"
                            @scorecards-updated="scorecardsUpdated"
                        />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </transition>
        </template>
```

Comment: Circling back to this.  I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts whatsoever. It seems odd that it would scroll to the top of the screen on a simple change to the visible status of a row.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem.

It's the default behavior of the anchor tags I am using for the visibility toggle.  Uggg...

I've tagged them to prevent default behavior and that has solved the issue.

```
<div>
     <a @click.prevent="toggleScorecardVisibility(scorecard.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-transparent-dark text-gray-500 m-0" href="#" role="button" :id="'scorecard_' + scorecard.id"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Scorecard Details" >
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-clipboard">
             <path d="M16 4h2a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H6a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h2"></path><rect x="8" y="2" width="8" height="4" rx="1" ry="1"></rect>
         </svg>
     </a>
     <a @click.prevent="onShowRebuildScorecardConfirmationModel(scorecard.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon text-red m-0" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Reset Scorecard" >
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-refresh-cw"><polyline points="23 4 23 10 17 10"></polyline>
              <polyline points="1 20 1 14 7 14"></polyline><path d="M3.51 9a9 9 0 0 1 14.85-3.36L23 10M1 14l4.64 4.36A9 9 0 0 0 20.49 15"></path>
         </svg>
     </a>
</div>
```

This solves the problem.  The .prevent prevents the default behaviour of the anchor which will use the href to scroll to the given position.